# select * from mytable where idnumber = (select idnumber from othertable where othertable.column = n) 

Tags: sql-server-2005, sqlcommand

I got two tables with the same pk (`idnumber`)..  I want to select all column from `table1` where `idnumber` (table1's pk) is equal to `idnumber` (table2's pk where table2's column = "some value"..)

please help... thank you

Here's what I got so far..

```
SELECT     
    idnumber, fname, lname, mname, bday, gender, email, contact  
FROM         
    tblStudents   
WHERE     
    (idnumber =  (SELECT idnumber
                  FROM tblPayments
                  WHERE (payment1 = 0)))
```

It's not working...

I'm totally new to SQL Server.. just got started few days ago.. please help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming both tables share a common column, you can just perform an `INNER JOIN` and use the `WHERE` clause to perform additional filtering.

```
SELECT * FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.SharedId = B.SharedId WHERE B.Column1 = 'foo';
```

[SQL Join Fundamentals (2005)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

I think the specific query you are looking for is:

```
SELECT 
    S.idnumber,
    S.fname,
    S.lname,
    S.mname,
    S.bday,
    S.gender,
    S.email,
    S.contact

FROM tblStudents S 
    INNER JOIN tblPayments P ON S.idnumber = P.idnumber 
WHERE P.payment1 = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for your syntax.

```
    'SELECT     
    idnumber, fname, lname, mname, bday, gender, email, contact  
FROM         
    tblStudents   
WHERE     
    (idnumber =  ANY (SELECT idnumber
                  FROM tblPayments
                  WHERE (payment1 = 0)))'
```

This kind of syntax is not commonly used. You should use JOIN instead.